# How to connect Database in C++? What database to use?

Tags: c++, database-connection

What are the suitable database for Visual Studio C++?
How could I connect a database to C++?

Comment: suitable? What are your requirements?

Comment: Pretty much all of them are suitable :) If you want to just learn the ropes, stick with SQL Server Express, since it comes with VStudio (or can be downloaded for free), requires very little configuration and has a pretty advanced SQL (you hear me, SQLite?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your choice of a database is fully dependent on your requirements. [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) offers a nice and simple interface.

Answer (score 1):

Beginners to Microsoft C++ should probably stick with [SQL Server Express,](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/) since it is designed specifically to work with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a local database just for your application then check out SQLite.  They have a C++ library that is quite easy to use and you interact with it via normal SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all, popular DBMS provide a C connector. Some even provide a C++ one (generally a wrapper of the C driver).

So, I suggest you start by looking at which DBMS you want to use, then browse their documentation for how to obtain and use their driver.